# Consider defining a bean of type 'com.fsse2207.project_backend.service.ProductService' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot

Basically, I have created all of the pojo and layers(including the repository layer) necessary for Spring Boot to automatically implement MySql commands. When I trying to run the programme, I get the following command:
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.fsse2207.project_backend.api.ProductApi required a bean of type 'com.fsse2207.project_backend.service.ProductService' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.fsse2207.project_backend.service.ProductService' in your configuration.

It turns out there's sth wrong about the bean in my ProductApi. It says "
Could not autowire. No beans of 'ProductService' type found." How do I fix it?

The following is the interface under the service layer:

```
package com.fsse2207.project_backend.service;

import com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.ProductCreateData;
import com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.ProductDetailData;
import com.fsse2207.project_backend.exception.ProductFoundByIdException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

public interface ProductService {
    ProductDetailData createProductData (ProductCreateData productCreateData) throws ProductFoundByIdException;
}
```

The following is the service class:

```
package com.fsse2207.project_backend.service.impl;

import com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.ProductCreateData;
import com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.ProductDetailData;
import com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.entity.ProductEntity;
import com.fsse2207.project_backend.exception.ProductFoundByIdException;
import com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl {
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Autowired
    public ProductServiceImpl(ProductRepository productRepository){
        this.productRepository=productRepository;
    }
    public ProductDetailData createProductData (ProductCreateData productCreateData) throws ProductFoundByIdException {
        ProductEntity productEntity=new ProductEntity(productCreateData);
        if(productRepository.existsById(productEntity.getpId())){
            throw new ProductFoundByIdException();
        }
        return new ProductDetailData(productRepository.save(productEntity));
    }
}
```

The following is the Api:

```
package com.fsse2207.project_backend.api;

import com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.ProductCreateData;
import com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.ProductDetailData;
import com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.dto.CreateRequestDto;
import com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.dto.CreateResponseDto;
import com.fsse2207.project_backend.exception.ProductFoundByIdException;
import com.fsse2207.project_backend.service.ProductService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ProductApi {
    private ProductService productService;
    @Autowired
    public ProductApi(ProductService productService){
        this.productService=productService;
    }
    @PostMapping
    public CreateResponseDto createResponseDto(@RequestBody CreateRequestDto createRequestDto) throws ProductFoundByIdException {
        ProductCreateData productCreateData=new ProductCreateData(createRequestDto);
        ProductDetailData productDetailData =productService.createProductData(productCreateData);
        return new CreateResponseDto(productDetailData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

I didn't add the `implements` keyword in the class definition of `ProductServiceImpl` so it was not connected to the bean, aka the interface, aka the service layer.

Comment: Great you shared your solution with us! Though I am afraid the SO community might consider this as a typo or lapse which could mean your question is subject to be closed for further answers (or to individual and not helpful to others).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not add annotation `@Service` for ProductService interface.
Moreover this can happen when you have your Class `Application` in "another package".
You can solve the problem using annotation `@ComponentScan (basePackages = {"your.company.domain.package"})`

Comment: It says "Redundant declaration: @SpringBootApplication already applies given @ComponentScan"

Comment: And I have removed the redundant annotation in the interface. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? Consider defining a bean of type 'com.fsse2207.project_backend.service.ProductService' in your configuration